# Change value in json on buttonclick

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a buttonclick inside a buttonclick.
My alert works atm.

```
        $scope.getid = function (order) {

            $scope.chosen.id = order.id;
            $scope.chosen.status = order.point;

            $scope.start = function (time) {
                alert(order.point)
            }



        };
```

I want to change order.point and give it a new value

```
            $scope.start = function (time) {
              (new value)
                order.point = ('2')
            }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: i update the question, hope you understand now

Comment: what's about HTML bit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @karlingen mentioned I also didn't understand your question properly, You cant add a function inside another function.  But in fact if you want to change the json value in angularjs on click action you can do like this

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9bjrmkh/)**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.start = function (records) {
        alert(records.col1);
        records.col1 = 'test1';
        alert(JSON.stringify($scope.records));
        
    }
    $scope.records = {
        col1: 'a1',
        col2: 'd1'
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Controller">
    <button ng-click="start(records)">Change</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much , i just used this line records.col1 = 'test1'; and it owrked for me

Comment: if i want to save the new value into json. $http.post("localhost"), how do i include the parameters?